graph search API returns 0 results
I develop the code bellow in my dev tenant were the list has 5897 items
  const searchRequest = {
    requests: [{
        entityTypes: ['listItem'], 
        query: { queryString: `Author:"avu@ecgmc.com" AND path:"${window.location.origin}/sites/dpc/Lists/DPCJobMaster"` },
        size: 0
    }]  };
try {
    const rep = await _client.api('/search/query').post(searchRequest);
    console.log(rep.value[0].hitsContainers[0].total)
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
}

It worked fine to show if a user ever entered an item to the list.
When deployed in production, where the list has 44699 items, it always return rep.value[0].hitsContainers[0].total = 0 .
I tried with REST api but I get:
"The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."
Some users created more then 5000 items and there is an index on created by.
Anyone has a solution to figure if a user created any items?
Thank you
